# Deferred binding failed error when adding presenter with GWT Platform

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I am not sure why I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for
>   'com.mygwt.client.core.FrameView$Binder' (did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?)

Although the View and Presenter java files have the same code pattern as with the working Views and Presenter I have in my code.

Comment: What could be causing this? Here is the complete error log: http://pastebin.com/SwzRYX9v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is using external JARs and they require to be inherited in the main module for GWT

You need  to add entry for this API in your gwt.xml

```
<inherits name='com.mygwt.client.core' />
```